# Ckfinder Browser Disabled for security reason ASP.net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckfinder

I can not find where is the problem the Web.Config that came with the Ckfinder 3 looks fine enabled=true 
where is the issue that's causing it not to run. I am running it under IIS as well and just trying to run the samples that it came with but it says disabled any answers please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you have to enable authentication in your connector. Please have a look at following docs page: http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/quickstart.html#quickstart_configuration_authentication

Comment: Thank You very Much. That Helped a lot.